# When may handcuffs not be used when arresting someone?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, police, arrest

This is a trope that occasionally comes up in various fora that handcuffs (and indeed any degree of force) when arresting someone should only be used if there is clear reason to think that it’s necessary. Yet empirically one never seems to see folks being led away by police without handcuffs, and handcuffs do seem to be the reflexive default/norm.

When are handcuffs to be used in arresting someone and when can (or should) there be foregone?

Comment: This is a question of a given police force’s policies and their implementation, not law.

Comment: [Citation needed]

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/police-powers-of-arrest-your-rights

Comment: https://network23.org/freebeagles/files/2013/05/Handcuffs-Guidance.pdf

Comment: Isn't policy based on law?

Comment: The law (explained in the guidance) is that in principle handcuffing someone is assault, so it may only be done when there are good reasons. The guidance gives guidelines what the “good reasons” might be; the law doesn’t say that.

Answer (score 5):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

You ask:

> When may handcuffs not be used when arresting someone?

The other two answers address:

- when may handcuffs be used;
- by necessary implication, when *must* handcuffs *not* be used

I agree that if the circumstances prohibit the use of handcuffs, then it is open to officers to not use handcuffs. But this answer addresses the full breadth of the headline question, to say when it is *permissible* to *not use* handcuffs during an arrest ("when *may* handcuffs not be used?").

There is no statutory requirement that police handcuff anyone during an arrest. The use of handcuffs is a conditional *entitlement*, not an obligation on officers.

> Police are entitled to arrest someone using handcuffs as long as they have a reason to bind the person being arrested and if they do so reasonably.
>
> *Street v. Toronto Police Services Board*, [2018 ONSC 4290, at para 86](https://canlii.ca/t/ht331#par86).

It has been suggested that there may be circumstances in which the use of handcuffs would be required by a private law [duty of care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_of_care), in order to *avoid* harm to the arrestee. See e.g. *Schuler v. Bergen*, [2010 SKQB 153, at para 22](https://canlii.ca/t/29x5b#par22) (suggesting that a decision *not* to handcuff could have resulted in a dog bite). But I have not found this duty to have been affirmatively recognized and applied in any reported judgment.

Answer (score 2):

### When it’s not reasonable

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

> A police officer or other person who exercises a power to arrest another person may use such force as is reasonably necessary to make the arrest or to prevent the escape of the person after arrest.

[s231](http://classic.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/leara2002451/s231.html) *Law Enforcement (Powers and Responsibilities) Act* 2002.

Use of handcuffs during an arrest is considered to be use of force by the NSW Police, therefore, they may only be used when “reasonably necessary”. In any case about this, the police position means that classifying handcuffs as “force” would not be in issue so the case would turn on if the manner of their use in the specific circumstances was reasonable.

The use of handcuffs for prisoner transfers is not considered force. AFAIK, this has not been litigated.

However, a recent (Feb 2023) [audit](https://www.lecc.nsw.gov.au/news-and-publications/publications/review-of-nsw-police-force-use-of-force-reporting-february-2023.pdf/@@download/file) of police practices has indicated some inconsistencies in the way police report handcuff use.

Police incident software (COPS) does not have an explicit prompt for the use of handcuffs. As such, it can only be determined if they were used in an arrest if the officer mentions it in their description of what happened or if it is captured on body-cam. This means it is almost certainly underreported.

At the same time, while police training and manuals is clear that handcuffs represent force, that isn’t an option on the “Use of Force” screen. The audit recommended that this be changed. Even so, in 90 incidents where the narrative mentioned the use of arm restraints and wrist locks, which do have a tick box on the use of force screen, only 50 were recorded there - humans gunna human.

Comment: obviously, when it is not reasonable, the use is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

### [netherlands](/questions/tagged/netherlands)

I found a German paper ["Eigensicherung und Recht"](https://www.bka.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Publikationen/Publikationsreihen/PolizeiUndForschung/1_19_EigensicherungUndRecht.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=3) by the federal police that in part contains legalities. It cites a Netherland official ordonnance Art. 22 on page 179:

> Die niederländische Amtsvorschrift Art. 22 besagt:
>
> > „Der Beamte kann einer Person, die von Rechts wegen ihrer Freiheit beraubt wurde,
> > zum Zwecke des Transports Handschellen anlegen. Diese Maßnahme kann nur getroffen werden, wenn die Fakten oder Umstände dies berechtigterweise erfordern in
> > Anbetracht der Fluchtgefahr oder der Gefahr für Sicherheit oder Leben der Person,
> > die von Rechts wegen ihrer Freiheit beraubt wurde, des Beamten oder Dritter.“

> The Dutch official regulation Art. 22 states:
>
> > “The officer may give a person who has been legally deprived of his liberty:
> > handcuffs for transport purposes. This action can only be taken if the facts or circumstances reasonably require it
> > Considering the risk of escape or the risk to the safety or life of the person,
> > who was legally deprived of her freedom, by the official or by a third party.”

So in the Netherlands there is a clear line that the handcuffs need to be **reasonably required** to prevent flight or ensure safety. **Unless such circumstances are given, it is in conclusion banned to use handcuffs.** If there is no danger or flight risk, the handcuffs not just can be forgone, you can't use them in the first place.

### [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

The paper mentioned above starts on page 70 with discussions on handcuffs and similar. It is mainly talked about as ***Fesselung*** (tying) since handcuffs are a subtype of any means to deprive someone of movement. It cites the 1977 [Model draft of a uniform police law](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musterentwurf_eines_einheitlichen_Polizeigesetzes) in the start, which became the basis of very similar but not always identical formulations in the different Länder:

> Die für die Eigensicherung relevante Formulierung in § 40 ME PolG zur Fesselung lautet:
>
> > „Eine Person, die nach diesem Gesetz oder anderen Rechtsvorschriften festgehalten
> > wird, darf gefesselt werden, wenn Tatsachen die Annahme rechtfertigen, dass sie 1.
> > Polizeibeamte oder Dritte angreifen, Widerstand leisten oder Sachen beschädigen
> > wird, (...)“

> The wording relevant to self-protection in Section 40 ME PolG on restraints is:
>
> > “A person detained under this Act or other legislation
> > may be tied up if facts justify the assumption that: 1.
> > Attack police officers or third parties, resist or damage property
> > becomes, (...)"

#### Fact-based, Risk-based and Resistance

Nine of the 16 Länder took exactly or almost exactly that wording, without any relevant changes to the effect. However, some jurisdictions diverge noticeably:

- Saarland's § 55 S. 1 SPolG is a little tighter: the "or other legislation" was cut, leaving *A person detained under this Act may be tied up [...]*
- Hamburg formulates wholly differently and only needs a risk to safety in § 23 HmbSOG: *“A person may only be restrained if he or she is in official custody and a) there is a risk that he or she will attack people, damage property, or
  if she resists, (...)"*
- Berlin likewise points to the risk to safety, not the factuality, to justify cuffs in § 20 UZwG Bln: *“(1) Persons who are in the custody of law enforcement officers may be restrained if
  a) there is a risk that they will attack people, damage property or provide physical resistance;"*
- Federal police has a whole [law on application of force by federal police officers](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/uzwg), where §8 reads: *“Anyone who is in the custody of law enforcement officers may be restrained if 1. there is a risk that he will attack law enforcement officers or third parties, or if he resists;”*
- Incarcerated people under trial can be cuffed and tied according to § 119 Abs. 5 Nr. 1 StPO, if *“... 1. there is a risk that he will use violence against people or (...), or if he resists...”*
- Mecklemburg-Vorpommern's § 106 SOG M-V and Schleswig-Holstein's § 255 LVwG diverge from those by having two very similar sections, that facts only go to the risk of damage but facts can't justify an assumption of resistance. Resistance is wholly separate here. The wording is *“A person detained under this Act or any other law may to be tied up, 1. if facts [MV:justify/S-H: speak for] the assumption that they a) attack other people or damage things of no small value becomes, (. . .) 2. if she resists.”*
- Baden-Würtemberg's VwV zu § 52 PolG BW differs from all of them as they demand resistance or anticipated resistance, or *special circumstances* that require it. *“2. A person may only be tied up – if they resist or, taking into account the circumstances of the individual case, it can be assumed that they will resist, (...) – if it is necessary due to special circumstances when transporting people in custody.”*
- Saxony's § 31 SchsPolG and § 32 SchsPolG regulate tying by using the **proportionality** standard.

So there is a distinct split of jurisdictions on tying (Fesselung):

- 10 in which the fact-based assessment of [anticipated] danger or [anticipated] resistance justifies tying.
- 2+federal where a risk-based assessment of danger or actual resistance justifies tying.
- 2 in which a fact-based assessment of danger or actual resistance justifies tying.
- 1 in which anticipated or actual resistance or special circumstances for transport justify tying.
- 1 in which the use of tying is wholly dependent on proportionality.

**Unless there is a justification** under the circumstances **that allows the use, the use of handcuffs is banned.** So if you don't pose a risk based on the above standards and don't resist, then the handcuffs not just can but have to be forgone. **No resistance and no danger means no handcuffs.**